# Download a File from a URL and save it on local folder, the link of it is as shown below in the question body

Tags: javascript

http://Company site/download_file?file_name=28528082-002-SH01.TIF&file_handle_name=MTIObjectHandle-0002-1~R~DghrOwfkoktsvsuGKP1--Pg7~p4Tiff~DELPHIDB~~

And the form selecting inspect element

```
<a href="download_file?file_name=28528082-002-SH01.TIF&amp;file_handle_name=MTIObjectHandle-0002-1~R~DghrOwfkoktsvsuGKP1--Pg7~p4Tiff~DELPHIDB~~" target="_self">28528082-002-SH01.TIF</a>
```

I am not a Java programmer and I'm trying some of the codes from the internet but none of them work as I needed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Firstly please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  
SO is not a coding service, if you need help, you will need to show the work you have done so far, and explicitly mention what issues you are having. Second, the question reads Java but is tagged Javascript, please fix the question as well

Comment: Also, this doesn't seem like something that needs either java or javascript.  E.g., `wget` or `curl` seem like better already-written utilities for this.

Comment: It is not clear if YOU are looking to download this file (in which case use `wget` or `curl` as suggested above) or if you want other poeple to be able to download this file from a web page (using the link you provide) and it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="download"  onclick="downloadFile()">download file</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('download').onclick = async function downloadFile(){
    let s = await fetch(URL_OF_THE_FILE);
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    const blob = new Blob([await s.arrayBuffer()], { type: s.type });
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = NAME_OF_THE_FILE;
    link.click();
}
</script>
```